# Formatar objeto com array de objetos nas propriedades - problema de escopo de variável

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promises, postman

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema no retorno de um webservice, faço uma query para obter Categorias, e depois outra para obter os itens daquela categoria. O objetivo é montar um retorno no padrão:

> ```
> {
>  "categoryId" : 1,             <--- resultado da query 1
>  "category" : "Alimentos",     <--- resultado da query 1
>  "items" : [{
>              "eventItemListId": 34,
>              "itemId": 31,
>              "item": "blabla",
>              "amountNeeded": 4,
>              "unityId": 1,
>              "unity": "Un",
>              "addedBy": "1"
>             },
>             (...)              <--- Este array de objetos vem da query 2
>   ]
> }
> ```

Meu webservice está conforme a seguir:

```
getEventItemListByCategory: (eventId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { connection, errorHandler } = deps
    const sqlData = [eventId]
    connection.query(process.env.QUERY_CATEGORY_ALL, sqlData, (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        errorHandler(error, 'Falha ao obter lista de categorias', reject)
        return false
      }
      var ret = []
      for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          let row = results[i]
        console.log(row.id + ' | ' + row.description)
        const sqlData = [eventId, row.id]
        connection.query(process.env.QUERY_ITEM_EVENT_ITEMS_BY_CATEGORY, sqlData, (error, results) => {
          if (error) {
            errorHandler(error, 'Falha ao obter lista de itens evento', reject)
            return false
          }
          ret.push({
            categoryId: row.id,
            category: row.description,
            items: JSON.stringify(results)
          })
        })
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ret))
      }
      resolve({ eventItems: JSON.stringify(ret) })
    })
  })
}
```

Na linha onde faço log no console, o resultado é (aparentemente ok):

```
[{"categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","items":"[  {"eventItemListId":34,"itemId":31,"item":"blabla","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":4,"unityId":1,"unity":"Un","addedBy":"1"},{"eventItemListId":36,"itemId":38,"item":"lalala","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":4,"unityId":1,"unity":"Un","addedBy":"1"},{"eventItemListId":5,"itemId":7,"item":"Linguiça","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":5,"unityId":4,"unity":"Kg","addedBy":"1"},{"eventItemListId":6,"itemId":10,"item":"Pão de alho","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":2,"unityId":2,"unity":"Pc","addedBy":"3"},{"eventItemListId":4,"itemId":5,"item":"Picanha","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":3,"unityId":4,"unity":"Kg","addedBy":"2"},{"eventItemListId":3,"itemId":3,"item":"Refrigerante","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":12,"unityId":5,"unity":"L","addedBy":"1"},{"eventItemListId":35,"itemId":32,"item":"Teste inclusão","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":10,"unityId":1,"unity":"Un","addedBy":"1"},{"eventItemListId":1,"itemId":1,"item":"Vodka","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":6,"unityId":3,"unity":"Gf","addedBy":"1"},{"eventItemListId":2,"itemId":2,"item":"Whisky","categoryId":1,"category":"Alimentos","amountNeeded":6,"unityId":3,"unity":"Gf","addedBy":"2"}]"},
{"categoryId":2,"category":"Infraestrutura","items":"[
  {"eventItemListId":7,"itemId":12,"item":"Caixa de som","categoryId":2,"category":"Infraestrutura","amountNeeded":2,"unityId":1,"unity":"Un","addedBy":"3"},{"eventItemListId":10,"itemId":20,"item":"Carvao","categoryId":2,"category":"Infraestrutura","amountNeeded":2,"unityId":2,"unity":"Pc","addedBy":"2"},{"eventItemListId":11,"itemId":21,"item":"Gelo","categoryId":2,"category":"Infraestrutura","amountNeeded":8,"unityId":2,"unity":"Pc","addedBy":"2"}]"},
{"categoryId":3,"category":"Outros","items":"[
{"eventItemListId":8,"itemId":18,"item":"Baralho","categoryId":3,"category":"Outros","amountNeeded":2,"unityId":1,"unity":"Un","addedBy":"3"},{"eventItemListId":9,"itemId":19,"item":"Narguile","categoryId":3,"category":"Outros","amountNeeded":1,"unityId":1,"unity":"Un","addedBy":"3"}]"}]
```

Mas o webservice, ao ser testado no Postman não retorna valor. Ao fazer um teste movendo o 'console.log' para fora do escopo que está, ficando exatamente antes do 'resolve', realmente loga arrays vazios.

Já fiz o teste de alterar o local da declaração da variável em todos os blocos, mas não consigo montar o retorno como desejado até o escopo final de retorno. Alguém consegue me explicar onde está o erro exatamente?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está resolvendo a promise antes de terminar as `querys` dentro do `for`. Tente verificar se é a última iteração antes de retornar a resposta para o cliente. O código ficaria próximo ao abaixo:

```
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    let row = results[i]
    console.log(row.id + ' | ' + row.description)
    const sqlData = [eventId, row.id]
    connection.query(process.env.QUERY_ITEM_EVENT_ITEMS_BY_CATEGORY, sqlData, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            errorHandler(error, 'Falha ao obter lista de itens evento', reject)
            return false
        }
        ret.push({
            categoryId: row.id,
            category: row.description,
            items: JSON.stringify(results)
        })

        // Validar indice antes de resolve a promise
        if (i === results.length - 1) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ret))
            resolve({ eventItems: JSON.stringify(ret) })
        }
    })
}
```

O comando `connection.query` responde de maneira assíncrona, consequentemente você deve ter certeza que foram finalizados antes de retornar o array para o client. Por isso, o ideal seria criar uma lista de promise para cada execução de query e resolver a promise principal no término de todas as promises utilizando [promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Eu estou começando nesta linguagem, entendi a lógica, mas não tenho certeza como implementar. Pelo que pesquisei, teoricamente preciso passar para o Promisse.all o array com as iterações de connection de cada categoria, o que ao final retornaria os blocos categoria->itens. Certo?

Comment: Consegui fazer com sua validação do índice, mas precisei alterar meu primeiro loop, atribuindo o results da primeira query para uma nova variável.